# Convert a date in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, date

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a date row in UTC time, such as `12/6/2012 11:14:32`

I want GMT+2 local time, so how can I convert the date in Google Drive?

And, if not possible, is there a way to do that in Excel, at least?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MS Excel try this:

`=A1+TIME(2,0,0)`

Same with Google:

```
=A1+Time(3,0,0)
```

Adds 3 'Hours', 0 'Minutes', 0 'Seconds' to the date/time value of A1

Additionally if only you use the main sheet you can go into the sheet settings and change it's timezone accordingly.

Comment: It's the same for Google Spreadsheet. Straight forward solution!!

Comment: This hard-codes the time offset, though. What if daylight savings time changes don't happen at the same time between the two timezones? Seems like an incomplete solution